# How to save a Vector<Vector<PointF>> into a ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, vector, arraylist, vector-graphics

I have a simple question which I am unable to solve. I have a `Vector<Vector<PointF>>` object that I want to save into a ArrayList. I tried doing this:

```
ArrayList<Vector<Vector<PointF>>> my_arraylist = new ArrayList<Vector<Vector<PointF>>>();
```

and saving like this:

```
 public void setMyArrayList(Vector<Vector<PointF>> polyLines) {
        my_arraylist.add(polyLines);
        this.my_arraylist = my_arraylist;
 }
```

When I try to fetch a specific element in my_arraylist, I always get the last element in my_arraylist. Is there a specific way to save a `<Vector<Vector<PointF>>` into ArrayList?

Comment: Why are you doing **this.my_arraylist = my_arraylist;** it makes no sense. can you add the code where you access the element.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. First I retrieve the whole ArrayList where I saved the elements:

public ArrayList<Vector<Vector<PointF>>> getMyArrayList() {
     return my_arrayList;
    }

I access the element like this:

ArrayList<Vector<Vector<PointF>>> returned_arrayList = getMyArrayList();
int index = 0;
Vector<Vector<PointF>> my_data = returned_arrayList.get(index);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I had to create a `Object` and store in it by cloning the `Vector` Array:

```
Object temp = new Object();

temp =  polyLines.clone();
```

and store the temp value in my `Arraylist<Object>.` Convert it back to `Vector<Vector<PointF>>` whenever I needed to use a specific element in arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

I saw only a little problem with your initialization

```
ArrayList<Vector<Vector<PointF>>> my_arraylist = new ArrayList<Vector<Vector<PointF>>>();
```

, and removed some unnecessary code:

```
public void setMyArrayList(Vector<Vector<PointF>> polyLines) {
    my_arraylist.add(polyLines);
}
```

I see no reason, why this should not work.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad, I initialize correctly but still does not work.

Comment: I am very sure that the problem is not in the code, you showed us. Either there is a problem in the code you call `setMyArrayList(..)` ore in the code you read from the ArrayList.

Comment: You are right. It looks like the Arraylist is updating with wrong values. I will check my set method.

Comment: I think I know the issue now. The Vector<Vector<PointF>> that is being stored in Arraylist looks like a series of android.graphics.pointf values. As soon as I store a new one, since android.graphics.pointf values reflect, they replace all arraylist elements with exact same android.graphics.pointf values.

Answer (score 0):

So you always get only the latest element you added to the ArrayList? This would suggest that before you add values to the ArrayList you either clear() the ArrayList or create a completely new empty ArrayList.

Your problem is not in the code you have shown us.

Try adding debug output like below. If the object reference written to System.err changes every time you call setMyArrayList then it indicates that you somewhere create a new ArrayList and thus discard all old values you have added there. Use a logging framework if you have one.

```
public void setMyArrayList(Vector<Vector<PointF>> polyLines) {
    System.err.println("Appending to ArrayList " + my_arraylist + ", size " + my_arraylist.size());
    my_arraylist.add(polyLines);
    this.my_arraylist = my_arraylist;
}
```

Comment: Hi Torben, When I debugged like in your comment, I saw that the issue is with the value in polylines. Since polyLines is a Vector<Vector<PointF>>, the pointF references in it are the ones drawn latest on canvas in the form of a series of android.graphics.pointf values. I am trying to find a way to store them as a object.